# Rejected edit: should I avoid adding a single relevant tag in the future?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I stopped by [a Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183870/how-to-get-the-frequencies-of-fft-array-currently) as I noticed it was using FFT. I recently used [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) to do some FFT transformations, so I was curious what the user was doing, as I noticed they were using Python. It turns out they were using NumPy.

I figured that adding the [`numpy`] tag might get some experienced users to look at this user's problem, as there are several areas where NumPy may have caused the issue.

[My suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22476429) was rejected, which is fine by me, but I'm not sure if it was rightly so.

[image: Suggested edit review result with two Reject votes]

Is it just me or is this a little bit harsh? Maybe I'm out of touch, but I think it would have been a useful tag. I'd rather not make the same mistake again for everyone's ease, if I'm wrong.

Comment: How did you explain your edit? That is usually where it makes or breaks. You may know the nitty gritty of it, don't expect reviewers to have the same understanding of the situation as you have. Only adding a tag is also suspect, there was nothing else to edit in the post? When you edit, you are expected to edit everything (obvious) that needs fixing.

Comment: @Gimby "How did you explain your edit? That is usually where it makes or breaks." [I think you don't know that reviewers need coffee.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199589/213575)

Comment: Here the specific suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22476429

Comment: So yeah, "added numpy tag" does not explain WHY it was added ;) Coffee is optional.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If I avoid an edit if I don't believe I can't fully address all the problems with a question?

Comment: @HowardP I have full faith in the fact that this will never be true. Because it if is true, you probably want to edit things you maybe shouldn't be editing to begin with, like fixing problems in code ;)

Comment: You can also leave a comment for OP suggesting specific tags to add, if you think they will improve chances for the question to be answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple of remarks here:

- If you're going to edit the post, make sure you improve *everything* that needs to be improved.  Because your edits go into the review queues, it's important that you maximize your efforts so that reviewers aren't making guesses at whether or not the tag is appropriate.

  At a minimum, you should've corrected the spelling on "understand".
- The question doesn't appear to be *about* NumPy.  The question appears to be more about Matplotlib given that they're wrestling with their plot.  Making a naive guess, it seems like there could be something wrong with their graph resolution, which cuts off at the thousandths place.  Unless there's something grossly wrong with their calculation, any detail about NumPy is noise to the problem at hand.

Comment: Oh wow, how about that, the answer on the question actually confirmed my naive assumption.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'd still believe that tag would have been useful. If you used JQuery in a question, would the JQuery tag not be useful?

Comment: If the question were predominantly about me trying to get my D3.js graph to display data, and I just so happened to be using jQuery to seed the data, **but I was otherwise able to demonstrate that the seeding of the data was *fine***, then no.

Comment: Okay, this seems like an edge case with blurred lines, but I suppose I'll just have to accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with NumPy, they are talking about matplotlib, so there isn't really a reason to add the tag unless you know that the tag is relevant to the question.

Second, the edit reviewers often make a final decision on a suggested edit by the edit description. Depending on how you described your edit, a reviewer may have declined it on that basis.

Finally, if you are going to add a tag, then make sure you look at the rest of the question body as well! Don't miss anything that could be edited in the body along with a tag. If you only add a tag when there are other things to be fixed, that could be a reason for a declined edit.

Comment: The user imported NumPy as np, and use it in 5 out of the 14 lines of code they wrote. I wouldn't quite say has that there's _nothing_ to do with numpy. Thank you for your advice in regard to making better edits.

Comment: @HowardP I see. I myself am not very proficient in Python, but seeing that now makes sense. But I am glad the rest of the advice made sense. Maybe the last paragraph explained the rejection?

Comment: yes it did, thanks, I wasn't fully aware of proper editing etiquette (say that three times fast!) and will keep it in mind going forward.

Comment: @HowardP Sounds good, happy to help and explain